# C: Save on a txt file the URL from another text file

Tags: c, multithreading, file, text

I need to make a program in C that connects to a web server and download its index.html file. I have already done this correctly but I'm struggling on the second part of the program, the specifications says:

> If the page contains complete http references, launch a concurrent
>   thread to get that page and save it to disk as a file (as before). A
>   complete reference means starting by ”http://” and ending by ”.html”

While I have already done the code to launch the Thread I don't know how to get all URLs.

This is the pseudocode that I want my thread to execute (and that I think it should work):

```
Open File;

Read File;

Fill the buffer;

LOOP:
Search for "http://", Save Position1
Search for ".html" from the previous saved position, Save Position2
Save all the string that goes from Save Position1 to Save Position2 in a txt.file using the System Call Write.
```

I've tried functions like strstr and even calculating the size of the file and trying if conditions in a gigantic for statement but anything returned the desired results.

Please keep in mind that I'm a begginer on C programming >.<

Comment: I think I understand that you should fetch the reference and save its contents to file, not just the reference itself. Also, unless you have precise instructions to use `write()`, don't use it, please stick to `fwrite()` (and companions) for the moment.

Comment: I first did all the code using fopen, fwrite, etc, until my teacher said that I must use the most basic system calls so yeah I need to use write.

How can I fetch the reference? I don't understand what you're trying to say with that

Comment: OK, if it's the teacher's request I guess it's fine. I think you should fetch the reference the same way you are fetching the initial *index.html*, so you should make a handy function for that (Are you using *cURL*?). If you are not convinced, maybe you should ask the teacher for clarifications. I don't think it would make much sense to spawn a thread to just write a string to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could use strstr for extracting the links from a file:

```
char str[32]="http://example.com/index.html";
char *p = strstr(str, "http://"), *q;
if (p != NULL) {
    q = strstr(p, ".html");
    if (q != NULL) {
        for (char *x = p; x < q + 5; x++)
            printf("%c", *x);
        printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Also note that while strstr is thread-safe, the needle and haystack pointers must be protected by mutexes or semaphores. Be careful when you use it in thread environments.

Instead of printf in the above code, write your favorite file I/O function - using write, fwrite or fprintf.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't get it to work, my program downloads and index.html file which contains a lot of URLS, in your code you're only using a string of 32 characters but in my case my buffer it's something that has like 10000 characters, and some of them are from an URL.

Another question, how should I make the loop? With the read function I can put all the file into a buffer but would this be the right method? I'm not sure..., maybe using a smaller buffer will help?

Thank you very much, I didnt expect a response that fast

Comment: @LunarParks The code is an example for your scenario. You must adapt the code as you need. You should read file a specific amount of characters or a single line, at a time till EOF or if you want to use the file like a `char*` memory use something like `mmap()`.  see `man 2 mmap`